# ListView HasUnevenRows does not work in xamarinforms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

good afternoon, i have a listview with grid with two labels in the first column and an image in the second column, it happens that the image is disrespecting, without the image the label is in the correct size.

My problem is that the label doesn’t show all her content when it has the image

When you have the image the labels are wrong. [image with resized error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dCPa.png)

Without the image, which would be expected but I don't know how to fix it for the cells to resize
[error-free image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSnss.png)

I've tried everything, if anyone can help me thank you

mycode

```
    <ListView
    x:Name="ListView_ListaRotas"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    ItemTapped="ListView_ListaRotas_ItemTapped"
    Refreshing="ListView_ListaRotas_Refreshing"
    SeparatorVisibility="None">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame
                    Margin="0,5"
                    Padding="5,0"
                    BorderColor="Gray"
                    Opacity="{Binding PermiteCheck, Converter={StaticResource Key=OpacityConverter}}">
                    <Grid
                        Margin="0"
                        Padding="1,0"
                        ColumnSpacing="0"
                        RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="18"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                Text="{Binding Ds_Observacao}"
                                VerticalTextAlignment="Start" />
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label
                                    FontSize="Medium"
                                    Text="{Binding Nm_Posto}"
                                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                <Image
                                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding HasSketch}"
                                    Source="rascunho.png"
                                    WidthRequest="20" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>

                        <Image
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            Source="{Binding TimeLine}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I found when your image is not very large,it will works well.You could report it to [forms github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues)

Comment: What about put your image into a Stacklayout?